# Subscribe to notifications for BLE with evothings plugin

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth

For an Android application with BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy), I am trying to subscribe to a ble device notification for heart rate measurement, using the evothings plugin. Can scan for devices, connect readout services but cannot subscribe.

Here are some code fragments:

```
app.connect = function(address, name)
{
    app.stopLeScan();
    console.log('connect('+address+')');
    document.getElementById('deviceName').innerHTML = address + " " + name;
    ble.connect(address, function(r)
    {
        app.deviceHandle = r.deviceHandle;
        console.log('connect '+r.deviceHandle+' state '+r.state);
        document.getElementById('deviceState').innerHTML = r.state;
        if (r.state == 2) // connected
        {
            console.log('connected, requesting services...');
            app.getServices(r.deviceHandle);
            app.subscribe(r.deviceHandle);
        }


    }, function(errorCode)
    {
        console.log('connect error: ' + errorCode);
    });
};
```

And the subscribe function:

```
app.subscribe = function(deviceHandle)
{

    console.log('Write Descriptor..');
    ble.writeDescriptor(deviceHandle,
        "00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", // Characteristic
        "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", // descriptor
        new Uint8Array([1,0]),
        function()
        {
            console.log('Status: writeDescriptor ok.');
        },
        function(errorCode)
        {
            // This error will happen on iOS, since this descriptor is not
            // listed when requesting descriptors. On iOS you are not allowed
            // to use the configuration descriptor explicitly. It should be
            // safe to ignore this error.
            console.log('Error: writeDescriptor: ' + errorCode + '.');
        });

    console.log('Subscribe..');
    ble.enableNotification(deviceHandle,
        "00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
        function(data)
        {
            console.log('byteLength: '+data.byteLength);
        },
        function(errorCode)
        {
            console.log('Error: enableNotification: ' + errorCode + '.');
    });

}
```

The output of the log shows the following:

```
Write Descriptor.. index.js:44
Subscribe.. index.js:62
connected, requesting services... index.js:211
Error: enableNotification: JSON error. index.js:71
Status: writeDescriptor ok. index.js:51
s1: 0 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. 2 chars. index.js:231
 c11: 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. 0 desc. index.js:248
  properties: PROPERTY_READ index.js:249
  writeType: WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT index.js:250
 c12: 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. 0 desc. index.js:248
  properties: PROPERTY_READ index.js:249
  writeType: WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT index.js:250
s2: 0 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. 1 chars. index.js:231
 c13: 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. 1 desc. index.js:248
  properties: PROPERTY_INDICATE index.js:249
  writeType: WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT index.js:250
  d26: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb index.js:268
s3: 0 0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. 3 chars. index.js:231
 c14: 00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. 1 desc. index.js:248
  properties: PROPERTY_NOTIFY index.js:249
  writeType: WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT index.js:250
  d27: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb index.js:268
 c15: 00002a38-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. 0 desc. index.js:248
  properties: PROPERTY_READ index.js:249
  writeType: WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT index.js:250
 c16: 00002a39-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. 0 desc. index.js:248
  properties: PROPERTY_WRITE index.js:249
  writeType: WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT index.js:250
```

I am interested in the hearth rate service listed as s3. But enabling notifications causes a JSON error. I hope someone could give some pointers.

Thanks in advance

Maverick2k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're using the library "easyble" from evothings-examples. Am I right?

Furthermore, the function "app.getServices" is not listed in your example, but it seems like it doesn't get to finish before you call "subscribe". Therefore, during "subscribe", the UUIDs and handles to the characteristics and descriptors are not available, and any attempt to use them fails.

I don't see how "writeDescriptor" could possibly succeed in this situation; perhaps its error handling is broken somehow.

Anyway, put the call to "subscribe" at the end of the "getServices" callback. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was using both a ble.evothings.com and easyble example interchangebly. So now I made my code completely depended on easyble, which wraps the ble.evothings.com API.